# wordpress javascript conflicts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am writing a Wordpress Plugin, and am wary of conflicts, so have been prefixing all my javascript functions with a relevant abreviation for my plugin, such as `myplugin_validate_email_address`

My plugin has a couple of shortcodes, and functions such as `myplugin_validate_email_address` could be used in both.

I am enqueing different scripts depending on which shortcode is being requested.

I tried to created a common.js script which would contain any common functions wihch both shortcodes might use, but have discovered that the scripts cannot reference them, probably because I am enclosing all the js in the following so that I can reference jQuery in the usual way.

`(function($){
.....
})(jQuery);`

Am I correct in thinking that anything contained in the above jQuery block is unique to this script, so do not have to worry about conflicts in any other script, which would mean I do not have to prefix all my functions? This is fine, it would just mean that I repeat my function for valid email rather than use a common.js file.

Comment: "could be used in both." > Are you worried of naming conflicts between JS and PHP functions? Because that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Javascript object, which can be referenced globally:

```
(function($) {

 my_js = {

    init : function () {    
        this.some_function();
    },

    some_function : function() {    
        // Add event handler or something else
    }
 }  
}) ( jQuery );

jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
 my_js.init();
});
```